# Gain access to getUserMedia object on Localhost on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, ios, localhost, webrtc

I am testing a webrtc implementation. I currently am able to get access to navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia on my desktop computer. However, when I
open up my localHost using my computers IP Address on my mobile phone, I get
a message saying that navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia is undefined.

on my computer I navigate to:
http://127.0.0.1:3000/basic-p2p/#8922097
(this works and allows me access to my video stream)

on my mobile phone I navigate to:

`http://<my ip address>:3000/basic-p2p/#8922097`

(this opens the webapp on my mobile phone, but the navigator object is undefined)

or

`http://127.0.0.1:3000/basic-p2p/#8922097`

(this doesnt open the webapp on my mobile phone, I just include it to be exhaustive)

the specific error I get is:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUserMedia')`

I see that it works on http: on my localhost on my computer but it doesnt work when
I switch to using my IP Address on either my computer or my phone. please help,
How can I give my mobile phone access to navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia while
still testing in development?

in case it helps, this is specifically the line that blows up when I switch to using my computers IP address to access localhost.

```
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false}).then(stream => {
          localVideo.current.srcObject = stream
          userStream.current = stream
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http works only for localhost or 127.0.0.1, For accessing video/camera feeds you will need https.

Looking at the above description, I assume you are using just and html page with video scripts. **Question**: Are you trying to access desktop camera from mobile.

Comment: ahh yes, HTTPS. I guess I was assuming since it worked on HTTP on my desktop, it should work on my mobile as well.


```Question: Are you trying to access desktop camera from mobile.```
No, I am trying to access the video camera of my mobile device. But it's not working at the moment on mobile because navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia line above is giving me that undefined error. 


Thanks for this, I will deploy to get access to HTTPS and then hopefully that will work.

Comment: Hey man, thanks.
I deployed the app on Heroku, it gave me a free ssl certificate. This allowed me to be able to use the Navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia on mobile. Thanks again.